# C# Why can't we assign delegate anonymous method to var key word

Tags: c#, delegates

I am curious to understand the behavior of `var` in this particular scenario.

```
var action = delegate (string s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
};
```

The above code returns a **compilation error**

> cannot assign an anonymous type to implicitly typed variable

Why is C# compiler not trying to assign `Action<string>` delegate to `var`?

Maybe its a basic question but all I want is to understand the behavior.

Comment: what are you trying to do>?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, perhaps not implemented or some problems with the compiler to be able to do that.

Don't forget that delegates are methods signatures/prototypes and `Action` are types, that is not really the same thing, even if a `delegate` can be casted in `Action` or `Func`.

Hence if you want to use the `var` keyword you can cast by writing:

```
var action = (Action<string>)delegate(string s)
{
  Console.WriteLine(s);
};
```

Also you can simply use a *lambda* to have a more clean code:

```
Action<string> action = str =>
{
  Console.WriteLine(str);
};
```

And for only one instruction:

```
Action<string> action = text => Console.WriteLine(text);
```